# How best to make sure I have all data before triggering my completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused about how best to get my HealthKit data, specifically heart rate recordings. My problem occurs due a race condition, which is due to asynchronous calls, and completion handlers.

My app records a workout session, and eventually pushes that data to a remote server for cleaning, and analysis. I'm wanting to include heart rate data in the session syncing request.

A session consists of GPS, and other sensor data split into laps.

When I begin to sync a session I call the following function like so:

```
fetchSessionLapTimes(session: session) { (storedSessionLapTime, error) in
    //handle the received lap time data
    //At this point, I expect my storedSessionLapTime variable to 
    //contain my session lap times, and heart rate data
})
```

My `fetchSessionLapTimes` function is defined like so:

```
func fetchSessionLapTimes(session: Session, withCompletion complete: ((_ storedSessionLapTime: [SessionLapTime], _ error: Error?) -> Void)!) {
    var storedSessionLapTime = [SessionLapTime]()

    managedObjectContext.performAndWait { 
        //get session lap times from Core Data
        //this code works fine, as expected and populates
        //storedSessionLapTime
    }

    //now this is where my problem is. At this point I want to extract 
    //heart rate data for each lap time        

    let healthStoreService = HealthStoreService()
    for sessionLapTime in storedSessionLapTime {
        let start = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sessionLapTime.lapStartDate)
        let end = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sessionLapTime.lapEndDate)

        healthStoreService.fetchWorkoutData(startDate: start, endDate: end) { (success, error) in
            complete(storedSessionLapTime, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

My `fetchSessionLapTimes` function is defined as follows:

```
func fetchWorkoutData(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)!) {
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: hrType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {
        query, results, error in

        guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
            completion(false, error)
            fatalError("Error fetching workout data: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }

        if samples.count < 1 {
            self.debug.log(tag: "HealthStoreService", content: "No workout data found")
            completion(true, nil)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            for sample in samples {
                self.debug.log(tag: "HealthStoreService", content: "\(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: self.hrUnit))")
            }

            completion(true, nil)
            return
        }
    }

    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

As you can see, this function is asynchronous as well. If I run this code, I do not get back heart rate data for all laps. **How can I make sure I have heart rate data for all laps before allowing `fetchSessionLapTimes` to return?**

Comment: You could use a `Semaphore` or dependent `OperationQueue`.  You could also make use of promise kit like [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) or [Hydra](https://github.com/malcommac/Hydra)

Comment: You are calling completion block when `fetchWorkoutData` is finished for the first time.

Comment: try Operation with dependency https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation/1412859-adddependency?language=objc

Comment: You could add the tasks which are currently called in a `for` loop to a `DispatchGroup` and get a notification when all of them get completed. Then fire the completion of your `fetchSessionLapTimes`. Check this http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the `fetchWorkoutData` tasks from the `for` loop to a `DispatchGroup`. You will be notified when all of them complete and thus you can call the completion of your function then. Here is an example:

```
func fetchSessionLapTimes(session: Session, withCompletion complete: ((_ storedSessionLapTime: [SessionLapTime], _ error: Error?) -> Void)!) {
    var storedSessionLapTime = [SessionLapTime]()

    managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
        //
    }

    // Here you were putting async calls to a for loop and couldn't tell when all were completed
    // DispatchGroup is made exactly to handle this
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let healthStoreService = HealthStoreService()
    for sessionLapTime in storedSessionLapTime {
        let start = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sessionLapTime.lapStartDate)
        let end = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sessionLapTime.lapEndDate)

        // Adding the task to group
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        healthStoreService.fetchWorkoutData(startDate: start, endDate: end) { (success, error) in
            // notifying when this particular task finishes
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    // completion is called only when all of the DispatchGroup tasks are finished
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        // call completion here because all tasks completed 
        complete(storedSessionLapTime, nil)
    }
}
```